# In Smarty3, call a template function defined by the {function} tag from within a plugin function

Tags: php, symfony, smarty, smarty3

Smarty [`{call}`](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.call.tpl) built-in function is able to call a template function defined by the {function} tag. Now, I need to call a template function but **inside a plugin** function because I only know the function name inside the plugin.

**Plugin function:**

```
<?php

$smarty->registerPlugin('function', 'form_label', 'renderFormLabel');

function renderFormLabel($form, \Smarty_Internal_Template $template) {

    // find out which function to call based on the available ones
    $function = lookupTemplateFunction($template);

    $args = $form->getVariables();

    // How to call the Smarty template function with the given $args?
    // $html = $template->smarty->???($args); 

    //return $html;
}
```

**Template:**

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post">
    {form_label}
    ....
</form>
```

*This is an effort to support [Symfony2 Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html) in [SmartyBundle](https://github.com/noiselabs/SmartyBundle). Each form fragment is represented by a Smarty function. To customize any part of how a form renders, the user just needs to override the appropriate function.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should have been more specific in my first answer. The code for the renderFormLabel should look like this:

```
function renderFormLabel($form, \Smarty_Internal_Template $template) {

    // find out which function to call based on the available ones
    $function = lookupTemplateFunction($template);

    if ($template->caching) {
        Smarty_Internal_Function_Call_Handler::call ('test',$template,$form,$template->properties['nocache_hash'],false);
    } else {
        smarty_template_function_test($template,$form);
    }
}
```

In this case the attributes(paramter) passed to the renderFormLabel plugin by the $form array will be seen as local template variables inside the template function.

Comment: The [Smarty_Internal_Function_Call_Handler](https://github.com/smarty-php/smarty/blob/v3.1.27/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_function_call_handler.php) disappeared with Smarty 3.1.28. Is `(new \Smarty_Internl_Runtime_TplFunction())->addTplFuncToCache('test', $template, $form);` now the way to go?

Comment: or probably `(new Smarty_Internal_Runtime_TplFunction())->callTemplateFunction($template, 'test', $form, false);`

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to call template functions from inside plugins. But we originally did plan for this option so currently the API is different if caching is enabled or not. This may change also in future releases.

Assume you want to do something similar to 
  {call name=test world='hallo'}
from within a plugin:

```
if ($template->caching) {
   Smarty_Internal_Function_Call_Handler::call ('test',$template,array('world'=>'hallo'),$template->properties['nocache_hash'],false);
} else {
   smarty_template_function_test($template,array('world'=>'hallo'));
}
```

Note that the template function is called in the context of the template which did call the plugin.  All template variables known in the calling template are automatically know inside the template function.

The template functions do not return the HTML output, but put it directly into the output buffer.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can understand your need, you wish to call a named method with given known args.

Why not use a `call_user_func_array` call like :

```
call_user_func_array(array($template->smarty, $function), $args);
```

Comment: The real question is: what function to call? @UTews provided the answer to this. As we can see it requires a deep understanding of Smarty inner workings to actually get it.